# Get the Key and Value from Dictionary in Silverlight Application

Tags: c#, silverlight, dictionary

I need to get value from Dictionary(which is returned from Webservice) in silverlight application.

I get the dictionary Value in variable val .

```
 serviceclient.GetMappingCompleted += (obj, val) =>
{
              //here I need the Key and Value result 
           int key = ?
           string value = ?

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may access the dictionary using `val.Result`. Here is the code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> item in val.Result)
{
    int key = item.Key;
    string value = item.Value;
}
```

If you are looking for the first `KeyValuePair` in the dictionary you may try this (don't forget to add the `using System.Linq;` so the `First` method would be available) :

```
 var key = val.Result.First().Key;
 var value = val.Result.First().Value;
```